# Perfect Power algorithm loop is too long

Tags: python

I am working on a "Perfect Power" algorithm and seem to be running into memory issues. I have a solution outlined as follows which should give me the right answer, but it's possible I am looping through too many iterations. Not sure how to get around this. This code will not even finish running when I try to run it.

Here is the problem text:

"A perfect power is a classification of positive integers:

In mathematics, a perfect power is a positive integer that can be expressed as an integer power of another positive integer. More formally, n is a perfect power if there exist natural numbers m > 1, and k > 1 such that m<sup>k</sup> = n.

Your task is to check wheter a given integer is a perfect power. If it is a perfect power, return a pair m and k with m<sup>k</sup> = n as a proof. Otherwise return Nothing, Nil, null, NULL, None or your language's equivalent.

Note: For a perfect power, there might be several pairs. For example 81 = 3<sup>4</sup> = 9<sup>2</sup>, so (3, 4) and (9, 2) are valid solutions. However, the tests take care of this, so if a number is a perfect power, return any pair that proves it."

```
def isPP(n):
    for k in range(2, n):
        for m in range(2, n):
            if m**k == n:
                return (m, k)
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

This can benefit from a lot of optimizations, but the simplest one is the following:

```
def isPP(n):
    for k in range(2, n):
        for m in range(2, n):
            result = m ** k
            if result > n:
                break # break the inner loop only
            elif result == n:
                return (m, k)
    return None
```

But there are more optimizations that you can add to make it run faster, which I will leave for you to find.

There is no memory issue, and there isn't a reason for one, you're not really allocating any more space for variables inside the loop (I've added one allocation for `result`, which is overwritten each time `m` increases)`